# Escape double quote inside a single quote

Tags: linux, bash

```
for x in $(cat raw_tables.txt)
do
echo '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "<pass>",
        "sql" : "select * from "'$x'"",
        "elasticsearch" {
                "cluster" : "Search",
                "host": "<ip>",
                "port": 9300
        },
        "index" : ""'$x'"",
        "type": ""'$x'"" 
    }
}' | java \
   -cp "/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.3.1/lib/*" \
   -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.3.1/bin/log4j2.xml \
   org.xbib.tools.Runner \
   org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter


cat raw_tables.txt
table1
table2
table3
```

When i run that it comes out as

"index" : ""$x"",

I need it to come out as "index" : "$x",
I can't bypass the double quote it's producing and if I try escaping the entire thing with a single quote the script thinks it's stopped.

I've tried everything.. Anything would be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: why not remove one of the quotes in each pair?   `..."index:" : "'$x'"' ... `

Comment: What do you mean? Like removing the double quotes? As I said that would make the script think that the script has ended where the variable is.

Comment: No, you're in single quotes, double quote is just any other char within that context.

Comment: you want to temporarily terminate the single-quoting so `$x` variable will expand? Maybe you need `echo '... "index" : "'"$x"'",...'` . Note that is dbl-quote, single-quote, dbl-quote on both sides of `$x`. Good luck.

Comment: If I try that then the script thinks it has ended where the first variable is. Using any single quote without a double quote will end the script and result in a error.

Comment: I didn't get it right the first time, dbl-chk my comment for updates ;-) . Although, the `here` document answer below is getting my vote. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a here-document, this way you don't have to care about quoting (in this case, since the document doesn't need to contain any backticks or dollar signs):

```
while read x; do
  java ... lots of options \
    more options for java \
    and more options for java  <<END_DOC
{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "<pass>",
        "sql" : "select * from $x",
        "elasticsearch" {
                "cluster" : "Search",
                "host": "<ip>",
                "port": 9300
        },
        "index" : "$x",
        "type": "$x" 
    }
}
END_DOC
done <raw_tables.txt
```

The end marker (`END_DOC` in this case) needs to be flush to the left, with no indentation.

Comment: The plugin I'm using is JDBC Importer that will import all tables in the txt file to Elasticsearch. The developers have used echo ' { }' in their docuemtnation and I have only seen it being used that way. I have tried removing echo and the single quote to a doble quote but it doen't work. I have updated the code to show the java application that it sends the echo to.

Comment: @AlexRieker Updated my answer.

Comment: The code executed itself but the only problem is it execute all the code at once. Meaning it worked great, but could you make it so that each script executes one by one but all together?

Comment: @AlexRieker Less pretty, but works.  The advantage of a here-doc is that you can see exactly what it is, with no extra quotation marks.

Comment: You don't need `cat` here; `java` can read directly from the here document.

Comment: How would java read directly from the document? The only reason I have the text file is because the text file contains names of tables in a database that I want to import ito Elastic search. The java options are just Elasticsearch plugins that allow me to do this.

Comment: @AlexRieker back again! :-) sorry

Comment: @AlexRieker Piping the here-doc into java is the same as sending it to java's standard input. The code in my answer does that now without the use of cat. That's what chepner meant.

Comment: Thank you for helping, the code is working. But there is some kind of error with ElasticSearch. I will mark your answer as correct since the script itself works. You saved me a lot of time thank you!

Comment: You do have to care about quoting in the here document if it needs to contain a literal `$` or backtick (too lazy to remember how to type that in a comment with code formatting).

Comment: @tripleee Well, yes, if it had had any of them in there obviously. Maybe I expressed myself a bit carelessly. I was referring to the OP and this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to generate dynamic JSON like this, because you don't know if anything in the contents of `x` needs to be escaped (although in this case, a valid SQL table name is unlikely to need any special treatement). You should use something like `jq` to generate the JSON instead.

```
# This is not JSON itself; it is a filter to be used by jq
# to *generate* JSON.
template='{
        "type" : "jdbc",
        "jdbc" : {
          "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
          "user" : "root",
          "password" : "<pass>",
          "sql" : "select * from \($table)",
          "elasticsearch": {
            "cluster" : "Search",
            "host": "<ip>",
            "port": 9300
          },
          "index" : $table,
          "type": $table
        }
      }'

while IFS= read -r x; do
  jq -n --arg table "$x" "$template" | java ...
done < raw_tables.txt
```

Using `jq` solves many of the same quoting problems that a here document does as well.

---

You can also read the table names from standard input, instead of passing them as a JSON variable. You replace `$table` with `.` in the template, then call `jq` with the `-R` option instead of the `--arg` option.

```
template='{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
      "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
      "user" : "root",
      "password" : "<pass>",
      "sql" : "select * from \(.)",
      "elasticsearch": {
        "cluster" : "Search",
        "host": "<ip>",
        "port": 9300
      },
      "index" : .,
      "type": .
    }
  }'

while IFS= read -r x; do
    echo "$x" | jq -R "$template" | java ...
done < raw_tables.txt
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying other solutions and I'm trying yours right now and it's pickign up compling errors. 2 compile errors
^Cerror: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '}'

 "elasticsearch" {
                  ^
error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end

Comment: Your original JSON in the question is missing the `:` after the "elasticsearch" key.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH. NOW THE OTHER SOLUTION WORKS.

Answer (score 1):

here you go, remove one of the double quotes in each pair around `$x`

```
$ for x in table1 table2 table2; do
> echo 'bla bla bla
>       "index" : "'$x'"
>       bla bla bla'
> done
bla bla bla
      "index" : "table1"
      bla bla bla
bla bla bla
      "index" : "table2"
      bla bla bla
bla bla bla
      "index" : "table2"
      bla bla bla
```

Comment: As I said that will cause the script to think that the first variable is the end of the script.

Comment: This is a real run and the script didn't think so.  What kind of system are you using?  Did you try this at all?  Bash leaves single quote context alone.  So, double quotes in the script is treated the same as other chars.  There is no need to doubling or escaping them.  Perhaps I misunderstood the question.  Do you want the `$x` to be replaced by values in the for loop or literally left as `$x`?  If so what's the reason of the for loop?